# Why is my c++ code finishing with exit code 11 when using the stack?

Tags: c++, stack

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

int main() {
    std::string s = "()"; // Input

    std::stack<char> stack_;

    for (int i=0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s[i] == stack_.top()) {
            stack_.pop();
        }
        if (s[i] == '(') {
            stack_.push(')');
        }
        if (s[i] == '{') {
            stack_.push('}');
        }
        if (s[i] == '[') {
            stack_.push(']');
        }
        else {}
    }
    while(!stack_.empty()) {
        std::cout << stack_.top() << std::endl;
        stack_.pop();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I'm fairly new to C++ and trying to improve by doing a question on LeetCode.com every day. I test my code in CLion first, which is giving me a "Process finished with exit code 11" error for this code. The question I'm trying to solve is: https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/

This is just simply test code where I change the input of string s, and my strategy is to put bracket types on the stack then peel them off if the matching closing bracket is the next character, and then if the stack is empty at the end, the string passes the test.

I believe exit code 11 is a memory leak or segmentation fault error, but I can't figure out where to pinpoint where that could be happening by looking at my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest 2 things.  1.  you look at what happens if you call stack.top() when it's empty.
2.  you learn how to use your debugger.

#2 is ESSENTIAL for any future in software

Comment: Now may be a good time to learn how to use a *debugger*. With a debugger you can run the program and catch crashes as they happen. The debugger will then allow you to see where in your code it happened, and also allows you to examine the values of involved variables.

Comment: Because of your comments I've made it a goal to learn my debugger better. I was putting that off - can't give a solid reason why, but your comments have given me a good direction to point myself in. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's this line which is always called, even when `stack_` has just been created:

```
   if (s[i] == stack_.top()) {
```

calling `top()` on an empty stack results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I didn't know that. Because I had created the stack beforehand, I thought it would look at some random uninitialized value in memory at least, and then the 'if statement' would simply return as false without an error. I'll have to look more into why this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

std::stack::top description 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/top

You are trying to get a reference to top element of an empty stack, so you're getting an exception